# function template parameter deduction of template parameter vs of default template parameter vs of return type

Tags: c++, sfinae, template-argument-deduction, enable-if, function-templates

This is a question about how template deduction works when template parameter used as template parameter vs as default template parameter vs as return type.

### 1: plain template parameter

As tested using GCC and VS compiliation of below snippet fails to deduce template parameter defined by `std::enable_if_t`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template< class T, std::enable_if_t< std::is_integral_v< T > > >
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
{
   left = left ^ right;
   right = left ^ right;
   left = left ^ right;
} 

template< class T, std::enable_if_t< std::is_floating_point_v< T > > >
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
{
    left = left - right;
    right = left + right;
    left = right - left;
}

int main()
{   
   int i1 = 10;
   int i2 = -120;
   std::cout << i1 << " " << i2 << std::endl;
   SwapInPlace( i1, i2 );
   std::cout << i1 << " " << i2 << std::endl;

   double d1 = 1.1234;
   double d2 = 2.5678;  
   std::cout << d1 << " " << d2 << std::endl;
   SwapInPlace( d1 , d2 );
   std::cout << d1 << " " << d2 << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

> VS: error C2783: 'void SwapInPlace(T &,T &)': could not deduce
> template argument for '__formal'
>
> GCC: couldn't deduce template parameter -anonymous-

### 2: default template parameter

Declaring second template parameter as default template paramater makes deduction to work ok:

```
template< class T, class = std::enable_if_t< std::is_integral_v< T > > >
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
{...}

template< class T, class = std::enable_if_t< std::is_floating_point_v< T > >, bool = true >
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
{...}
```

Added `bool = true` to second overload just to avoid compilation error because it's not possible to overload function template based on default template parameter. Want to focus only on the fact that deduction works ok here. If there was only one template using default parameter, e.g. for `std::is_integral`, it would compile and work fine upon condition we pass correct parameters to it.

### 3: return type

In case of return type everything compiles and works well:

```
template< class T >
std::enable_if_t < std::is_integral_v< T > >
SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
{...}

template< class T >
std::enable_if_t < std::is_floating_point_v< T > >
SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
{...}
```

### 4: template parameter with default value

Another way to make this code compile is by adding default value for template parameter defined by `std::enable_if`. Added `* = nullptr` before last closing angle bracket, so if `std::enable_if` condition evaluates to `true` then our second parameter becomes `void*` with default value `nullptr`:

```
template< class T, std::enable_if_t< std::is_integral_v< T > >* = nullptr >
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
{...}

template< class T, std::enable_if_t< std::is_floating_point_v< T > >* = nullptr >
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
{...}
```

---

So the question is: how deduction works in this 4 cases: why it fails in first case and succeds in three other?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with `enable_if` so you can simplify the question considerably.  You wonder why `template<class T, void>` won't work, but why `template<class T, void* = nullptr>` does, right?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Not exactly, I wonder why it's working and why it's not working for the cases I listed. I most curios in why this is working for the case when default template parameter is used. But I still want to understand all other cases too.

Comment: Yes, and I say that you get exactly the same _without_ mixing in `enable_if`. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/z8h71o)

Comment: @TedLyngmo sure.
I need to rewrite the question then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove everything about `enable_if` in the question. It boils down to these three:

`void` is an invalid anonymous template parameter:

```
template<class T, void>
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right );
```

A `void*` as an anonymous template parameter with a default value is ok:

```
template<class T, void* = nullptr >
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right );
```

`void` as return type is ok:

```
template<class T>
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right );
```

If you'd changed the first case to a valid anonymous template parameter **without** a default value, like an `int` or `void*`, it would compile:

```
template<class T, int>
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right );
```

... until you tried actually using it. You'd then get "*couldn't deduce template parameter '`<anonymous>`'*" or similar.

Comment: Thanks for concise answer, the issue was precisely about anonymous `void` template parameter.

Answer (score 4):

> how deduction works in this 4 cases: why it fails in first case and succeds in three other?

---

First case

```
template< class T, std::enable_if_t< std::is_integral_v< T > > >
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
```

Suppose `std::is_integral_v` is true; with the `std::enable_if_t` substitution you get

```
template< class T, void>
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
```

that isn't a valid C++ code, because it's requested a `void` value (for a second template parameter) but `void` can't have a valid value.

Suppose you substitute a `int` (a type that accept a valid value) for the type of the second template parameter

```
// .........................................................VVVVVV
template< class T, std::enable_if_t< std::is_integral_v< T >, int > >
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
```

in case of integral `T` value you get

```
template <class T, int>
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
```

that is valid but... suppose the call is

```
int a{1}, b{2};

SwapInPlace(a, b); // compilation error
```

You have that `T` is deduced as `int` from `a` and `b` but the compiler can't decide a value for the second (un-named) template parameter.

So, to make a valid call, you have to explicit  the second template parameter calling the function

```
SwapInPlace<int, 0>(a, b); // OK
```

This way the call works because no deduction take place and explicitly say that `T` is `int` and the `int` parameter is `0`.

This works but is uncomfortable, because you have to explicit the `T` that can be deduced.

To avoid this problem, you can add a default value for the second template parameter

```
// .........................................................VVVVVV.VVVV
template< class T, std::enable_if_t< std::is_integral_v< T >, int > = 0 >
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
```

so, in case of `T` integral, you get

```
// ....................VVVV
template <class T, int = 0>
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
```

and now the simple call

```
int a{1}, b{2};

SwapInPlace(a, b); // OK now
```

works because `T` is deduced as `int` and the second template parameter is defaulted to zero.

Works but you can observe that you're in the fourth case, now (with `int` instead of `void *` and `0` instead of `nullptr`)

---

Second case

The second case is a bad idea.

```
template< class T, class = std::enable_if_t< std::is_integral_v< T > > >
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
{...}
```

When `T` is integral become

```
template< class T, class = void>
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
{...}
```

that is a valid code, with `T` that is deducible from `left` and `right` arguments and the second, un-named, argument is defaulted, so there is no needs to explicit it.

But when `T` isn't integral, the SFINAE failure throw away only the default value for the second template parameter, so you get

```
template< class T, class>
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
{...}
```

and the code is valid but the second template parameter isn't defaulted so has to be explicit-ed.

So, almost as in first case, you have

```
float a{1.0f}, b{2.0f};

SwapInPlace(a, b); // compilation error
SwapInPlace<float, void>(a, b); // compile
```

The bad part is that a default value doesn't distinguish a function signature; so if you have two `SwapInPlace()` alternative functions

```
template< class T, class = std::enable_if_t< std::is_integral_v< T > > >
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
{...}

template< class T, class = std::enable_if_t< not std::is_integral_v< T > > >
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
{...}
```

after the substitutions you have

```
template< class T, class = void>
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
{...}

template< class T, class>
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
{...}
```

So you have two functions with exactly the same signature (remember: the `= void` doesn't count). This is unacceptable for C++ rules so you have a compilation error.

Suggestion: avoid the second way because doesn't works when you have to develop alternative functions.

---

Third case

```
template< class T >
std::enable_if_t < std::is_integral_v< T > > SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
 {...}
```

This is the simplest case, as far I can understand.

In case `T` is integral, you get

```
template< class T >
void SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
```

that is valid code, so the function is enabled.

In case `T` isn't integral, you loose the return value

```
template< class T >
     SwapInPlace( T& left, T& right )
```

so the code isn't valid so the function is disabled.

---

Fourth case: see the first case

Comment: Thanks for details. About case when default template parameter is dropped in case when `T` isn't integral - the code you've provided as example just after `So, as in first case, you have` will compile in both cases - with deducted parameter and parameters provided in a call -  as you use ints there. Seems you've wanted to use `double` instead, thou it will not work in both cases - with deducted parameter and parameters provided in a call. Anyway there's some ambiguity in this section, could you please look into it?

Comment: @SoupEndless - Good point. Yes: in that case the example needs a non-integral type for values. Thanks; corrected (I hope).